# is there an eclipse plugin to debug python program on ec2 instance?

Tags: python, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I downloaded the AWS toolkit but I noticed that it only supports Java, I'm wondering if there is an Eclipse plugin to be able to run and debug python programs on ec2 instances?

Thanks